# Getting Error: Cannot find module "." at webpackMissingModule

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, pug

I'm trying to webpack an express application but I'm having the following problem wherever I try to retrieve the / page:

> Getting Error: Cannot find module "."     at webpackMissingModule

Here's code that reproduces this:

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 8088;

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on ${port}`));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Initially I thought it was because pug was not included in the modules so I tried adding `require('pug')` in the page but that just moved the error to the server launch rather than runtime.

Here's my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js')
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    __dirname
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].entry.js'
    }
}
```

I am using express 4.16, pug 2.0-rc4, webpack 3.8 and babel loader 7.1

I've also tried to include all node modules but then I get a different error (`dP.f` is not a function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because although you are excluding `node_modules` from being compiled by babel, they are still being included on your bundle.

You also need to ignore `node_modules` from being included into your bundle.

Install [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals)

`npm install webpack-node-externals --save-dev`

And add two lines to your webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals'); //include this

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js')
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [
                    __dirname
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules']
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // just add this
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].entry.js'
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's probably not ideal since I will not be able to deploy the bundle directly but rather would need to also install all modules on production. However I can probably fiddle with a whitelist to get it down to what I need